# Looking for a movie where there is a Powerful Board Game played by two brothers?

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the title. It's a board game where two brothers played it. When they played the board, it sent them to space? It's a board where I think it has different levels,each levels has a card, and each levels has different obstacles in space? One level in there, they even put their house being pulled by the sun? And there is also a part there where there is an astronaut.

Comment: Were they the Parker brothers?

Comment: Pretty sure it's Jumanji...... in Space.

Comment: according to the comments below, jumanji and zathura are both based on books by Chris Van Allsburg so it has its similarities.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sounds very much like John Favreau's  [Zathura](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0406375/)  (2005)

> Danny and Walter are two brothers who barely get along even while driving their parents to distraction as their older sister tries to ignore them. Despite their squabbling, the brothers manage cooperate enough to play an old mechanical board game named Zathura. However, after their first move, they find that the game has apparently flung them, their sister and their entire house into outer space. Furthermore, the brothers surmise the only way to return home is to finish the game. However with almost every move, new dangers arise as the siblings find themselves learning to cooperate in ways they never expected as they realize what they mean to each other.

Comment: Which of course is but a pale imitation of Jumanji ;)

Comment: Indeed.  I happen to think that any film without Robin Williams could be seen as being "pale"....

Comment: Both Zathura and Jumanji are based on books by Chris Van Allsburg, so the similarities aren't surprising.

Comment: @joanwolk I could be wrong here, but I think (as books) Zathura is the direct sequel to Jumanji too, centring around minor characters from the first book.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker: You are perfectly correct.Blurb for Zathura book: "On the last page of the Caldecott-winning book Jumanji, young Danny Budwing is seen running after his brother, Walter, with a game tucked under his arm. Now after twenty years, [the author] is ready to reveal what happens when Danny and Walter roll the dice. This time the name of the game is Zathura and the battling Budwing boys are in for the ride of their lives."

Comment: @BiscuitBaker I'm surprised that it wasn't marketed that way - I feel like it would have done better if it hadn't been seen as a ripoff by people who didn't know the books.

Comment: @Random832 - Zathura and Jumanji were both produced by different companies (Tri-Star and Columbia).  I guess there's enough of a reason not to promote a competing studio's film....

Comment: I went for the link. This is the movie I was looking for! The tile always makes me confused. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Tristar and Columbia are both subsidiaries of Sony, so they're not really competing, which makes it even weirder that they didn't directly tie-in to the original.

Comment: @HerrPink That depends on how independent they are. Occasionally subsidiaries do compete and may not work well together.